# Combining BCS content source with people result source into everything tab in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, bcs

I want to display the people result source along with other different results source including local SharePoint Results and some BCS connection content source in Everything tab.

Please suggest if anyone has any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The “Local SharePoint Results” result source includes the all items from the local SharePoint search index except People items.

If you want to display the people result source and Local SharePoint Results, it indicates you want to display all the items from the local SharePoint search index.

So the query text in the result source will be “{?{searchTerms}}”.

If you want to add some BCS content sources in the result source, you should use main content source and some BCS content sources in the result source. Then query text as below.

{?{searchTerms} ContentSource="main content source" OR ContentSource=firstcontentsource OR ContentSource=secondcontentsource }

After all, you could follow the steps below:

1. Create a custom result source using the query text above. Go to site settings->search->result source.
2. Go to the search result page for Everything tab. Go to site settings->search->search settings->in the Configure Search Navigation, find the url of Everything tab and go to the page for Everything tab
3. Edit the page-> edit the search result web part->change query->select the result source created in the first step.

More references:

Create A Search Tab In SharePoint 2013.

https://richardstk.com/2013/05/03/create-a-search-tab-in-sharepoint-2013/

Understanding result sources for search in SharePoint Server 2013

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn186229.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying. Let's first take to display the people results with Local SharePoint results. I went to SharePoint Admin and and create a new result source selecting the Local SharePoint in protocol list and gave  query text "?{searchTerms}" . after that I edit the search result web part and select the custom content source but still it is not returning people results in search.

Comment: @Suren 
The query text in the custom result source should be “{?{searchTerms}”.
And check if there is result as below in the search results.
“Administrator
 sp:80/my/Person.aspx?accountname=CONTOSO%5CAdministrator”

Comment: If I'm using the query   {?{searchTerms} ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople OR ContentSource:BCSSource} . It is only returning the results from People result and BCS source but it is not returning the results from SharePoint site libraries. even though I write library name explicitly in path. But still no luck.   Appreciate any help